# How to convert the headers key to uppercase?

Tags: android, webview, header

The headers key added by calling `webview.loadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> additionalHttpHeaders)` is finally converted to lowercase, and how to convert to uppercase.

```
HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Token", "dfds343");
webView.loadUrl("www.google.com", headers);
```

Comment: you want to convert `Token` to uppercase?